# What does it mean when someone says "I'm so over myself"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

I'm not native and I listened this statement in a film, in a contention between lovers:

A: "... Get over yourself"

B: "... I'm so over myself"

Based on the context the meaning should be obvious but I'm a little confused about  it.

Comment: B's response is non-standard, so it's impossible to tell what they meant without more context. But it was probably intended to mean "I'm not conceited/pompous (anymore?)." See here: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20over%20yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem "being over oneself" means no longer being enamored by one's own abilities, looks or perceived value.

The speaker has probably gone through recent happenings that help him/her have a more objective appraisal of themselves and their immediate environment.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm (so) over {somebody}" is usually used to mean "I used to be in love with {that somebody} but I'm not anymore", while "get over yourself" accuses the addressee of self-centeredness to the point of self-infatuation.

I'm guessing the two are juxtaposed here for comic effect, but context and visual cues would help us figure out what the second speaker meant.

Answer (score 0):

"Get over yourself"... is a away of saying come down, you aint that great.

"I'm so over myself"... is a form of self loathing, a moment in which someone is tired of how they deal with things, that all there decisions seem to always point in the wrong direction.